# How can I get the item "TWISTED SPIRIT"?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

I know that it should be dropped by Azudor (the second encounter).
But every time after I defeat him, he dropped "Arch Demon Spirit".
What should I do to get it from him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://valdisstory.wikia.com/wiki/Twisted_Spirit) :

> First off, after defeating Dhistahn, make sure not to execute him.
>   When meeting Azudor in the Mana Crystal Mines for the second time,
>   Dhistahn will join the fight. After defeating both of them, and the
>   second stage of Azudor, Twisted Spirit will drop afterwards

Tho, it seems that if you kill Azudor first or execute Dhistahn you wouldn drop the item. You need to follow theses steps very carefully. Some says it's even bad design from the game, since lots of player would kill Dhistahn on the spot; or even Azudor.